# Do Eclipse Plugins automatically use the settings specified in the Network Connections preferences tab?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, proxy, eclipse-plugin

Just wondering if this is the default procedure eclipse plugins take, or if I will have to manually grab that information from the preferences and apply it as part of my plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not automatic.

You can access the proxy information using the `org.eclipse.core.net.proxy.IProxyService` interface which is available as an OSGi service.